# select rows that do not have any foreign keys linked

Tags: sql, linq

i have 2 tables
Group and People

People has GroupId that is linked to Group.GroupId (primary key)

how can I select groups that don't have any people? in t-sql and in linq

thank you

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Update**

I've run four different ways to do this through SQL Server 2005 and included the execution plan.

```
-- 269 reads, 16 CPU
SELECT *
FROM Groups
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM People
    WHERE People.GroupId = Groups.GroupId
);

-- 249 reads, 15 CPU
SELECT *
FROM Groups
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM People
    WHERE People.GroupId = Groups.GroupId
) = 0

-- 249 reads, 14 CPU
SELECT *
FROM Groups
WHERE GroupId NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT GroupId
    FROM Users
)

-- 10 reads, 12 CPU
SELECT *
FROM Groups
    LEFT JOIN Users ON Users.GroupId = Groups.GroupId
WHERE Users.GroupId IS NULL
```

So the last one, while arguably the least readable of the four, performs the best.

That comes as something as a surprise to me, and honestly I still prefer the WHERE NOT EXISTS syntax because I think it's more explicit - it reads exactly like what you're trying to do.

Comment: SQL Server's Profiler. It tells you how many reads and CPU time each query took (I ran them one by one).

Answer (score 8):

My preferred method is a left-anti-semi join:

```
SELECT    g.*
FROM      Groups g
LEFT JOIN People p ON g.GroupID = p.GroupID
WHERE     p.GroupID IS NULL
```

I find it most intitive, flexible, and performant.

I wrote an entire article on various query strategies to search for the absence of data - have a look [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=QueryBasedUponAbsenceOfData&referringTitle=Home) if you're interested.

Comment: I dunno if I find it more intuitive than WHERE NOT EXISTS, but +1 nonetheless.

Comment: +1, outer join and checking for `IS NULL` is definitely a well-performing approach in mysql (not sure how it compares performance-wise to `WHERE NOT EXITS` in various SQL Server editions, though).

Comment: If the efficiency of the method didn't sell me, the wordsmithing of 'left-anti-semi join' sure did... ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest solution is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM GROUPS
WHERE GroupId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT GroupId FROM People)
```

Comment: When Nulls are allowed for column 'GroupId' in 'People', you should change the query to this:
SELECT * 
FROM GROUPS
WHERE GroupId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT GroupId FROM People WHERE GroupId IS NOT NULL)